# How to add a property in to HTML Tag use Jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to add a Property In to a tag while select that tag

I need to add Invalid property like this  ....aria-readonly="false" invalid>

### Page load Code:-

```
function setFieldRequired1(field) {

    var dropdownField=$("[data-metatype='dropdown'][name='./jcr:content/metadata/document_type']");

      if (!field.val()) {
        dropdownField.prop('invalid', 'invalid');
        dropdownField.attr('aria-required', 'true');
        dropdownField.attr('aria-invalid', 'true');
        var icons = $(dropdownField.siblings('.coral-Form-fielderror'));
        icons.show();
      }
       else
      {
         dropdownField.attr('aria-required', 'false');
        dropdownField.attr('aria-invalid', 'false');
        dropdownField.removeProp('invalid');
        var icons = $(dropdownField.siblings('.coral-Form-fielderror'));
        icons.hide();
      }

}
```

This code working fine But when I select same dropdown with empty value also i have to add that invalid property?
Any help?

Comment: So if you already have working code to add a property (or attribute), is your question actually "How do I respond to a change in selection in a dropdown?" Have you looked into the `.change()` method or read a tutorial about handling events with jQuery?

Comment: `dropdownField.attr('aria-invalid', 'true'` ... missing `);`

Comment: _"when I select same dropdown with empty value also i have to add that invalid property"_: `if (!field.val()) { ... } else { dropdownField.prop("invalid", "invalid"); }` ?

Comment: @Andreas Its working But only in Page load i want work that  when Select dropdown also

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use attribute names separated by hyphen in javascript.

You have to convert it to camel casing.

For example :

1. aria-required --> ariaRequired
2. aria-invalid  --> ariaInvalid

Comment: But My Question is why Invalid propery adding only load time? I need to add while change the dropdown also

Answer (score 0):

there are some small differences between attr and prop method in jquery. hope the samples explain it for you. and take care witch prop. second parameter has to be boolean not string.

Original HTML TAG

```
<div id="container"></div>
```

JS:

```
$('#container').prop('disabled', true);
```

generates:

```
<div id="container" disabled></div>
```

JS:

```
$('#container').attr('disabled','disabled');
```

generates:

```
<div id="container" disabled="disabled"></div>
```